# Java run python file containing a while loop

Tags: java, python

I am trying to use a python script to read an Arduino since java cant read my acm0 port
and it seems that this code prints null when it runs
This is my java code to run a python script

```
  try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "python3 Test.py ");
        while(p.isAlive()){

        }
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(in.readLine());

  } catch (Exception e3) {
    }
```

this is my Python Script

```
   import serial
   ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
   while(1):
     ser_bytes = ser.readline()
     print(ser_bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a shell script that ran the jar for the java program and then after the program was close i had it execute the python script

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar MacroGUI.jar
python3 main.py
```